# OpenWisk Docker Support install fails

Tags: docker, openwhisk

When I try to install the docker skeleton in OpenWhisk, it fails with this error:

`$ wsk sdk install docker
    tar: blackbox-0.1.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
    Could not install docker skeleton.`

Comment: Are you using OpenWhisk on Bluemix?

Comment: No, this is the open API host from github

Answer (score 2):

I speculate that you have not deployed OpenWhisk yet and are doing something like this.

```
> wsk sdk install docker
tar: blackbox-0.1.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Could not install docker skeleton.
```

To deploy the system, please follow the instructions at https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk#build-and-deploy-openwhisk.  You should end up with something like this:

```
> ant deploy >& /dev/null 
> wsk sdk install docker
The docker skeleton is now installed at the current directory.
> ls dockerSkeleton/
Dockerfile      README.md       buildAndPush.sh client          server
```

Comment: This is more of a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: No, it is deployed. The problem appears to be that the tar file is no where in the openwhisk project.

Comment: Now that this answer has been edited to be more useful, I retract my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the missing blackbox-0,1.0.tar.gz is supposed to be hosted by the api endpoint, but isn't included in OpenWhisk.

My workaround was to pull it from Bluemix by:

```
wsk property unset --apihost
wsk sdk install docker
wsk property set --apihost <openwhisk api host>
```

I opened an issue on it. 
https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/74